# Отключить масштабирование элементов формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в winforms c# vs2010 отключить автомасштабирование формы и её элементов, чтобы при любом масштабе windows(например 125%), всё отображалось как при обычном 100%(по умолчанию)?

Answer (score 1):

В свойствах формы есть параметр "AutoScaleMode" выберите None.
Если я все правильно понял, это поможет.

Comment: AutoScaleMode = none не помогло.

Comment: @olga и проверьте что AutoScale выставлен в false, иначе будет работать старый механизм скейлинга (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PashaPash не, `AutoScale` ни чего не дает, шрифты все равно плывут и разметка вместе с ними =( К тому же он устаревший, интелисенс его не показывает и студия предупреждениями кидается если настойчиво использовать.

Comment: @rdorn Я знаю что он устаревший, но он должен быть false чтобы работал AutoScaleMode. Мало ли что там топикастер навыставлял :) но могу ошибаться,  под винформы писал слишком давно.

Comment: @PashaPash в формах полно косяков, исправлять которые, видимо, уже не будут - "не модно", "устарело" и все такое. Я их нежно люблю, но когда вопрос касается красоты интерфейса, то лучше уже сразу WPF. Красивости в формах для мазохистов =)

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко, то на масштабирование можно повлиять, но полностью его отключить нельзя.

Параметр масштаба о котором вы пишете задает поправочный коэффициент DPI для компонентов WinAPI. Он собственно и нужен для того, чтобы менять размет всех интерфейсных элементов одновременно, например для слабовидящих. Контролы WinForms являются оболочкой над нативными компонентами WinAPI, следовательно ведут себя точно так же.

В теории `AutoScaleMode` должен отвечать за это поведение, но на практике работает не совсем так как должно. Кроме `AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None`, необходимо переопределить свойство `ScaleChildren`, чтобы отключить масштабирование дочерних элементов:

```
protected override bool ScaleChildren => false;
```

Но даже это не спасает от масштабирования шрифтов, из-за которого начинает "плыть" разметка. А если при этом для разметки используются `FlowLayoutPanel` или `TableLayoutPanel`, то все совсем грустно.

[Тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms) можно подробнее ознакомиться с возможностями по настройке масштабирования в формах и некоторых известных проблемах.

Если вам нужны независимые размеры элементов и прочие графические рюшечки, лучше изучить и использовать WPF. Можно, например, задать размер элемента в дюймах и он будет сохранять этот размер независимо от разрешения и прочих системных настроек.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста пример кода для wpf формы с заданием шрифта, который будет одинаков как при 100% (изначально при программировании), так и при, например, 125% у пользователя (сейчас у меня проблема с увеличением текстов в элементах формы). И еще вопрос: для перевода приложения c# из winform в WPF достаточно изменить (переделать) только конструктор формы (вытащить кнопки и т.п.), а код оставить?

Comment: @olga в том то и дело, что не достаточно просто заменить фреймворк. Потому и написал "изучить". WPF это отдельный мир, логика от WinForms там практически непригодна, но альтернатив для красивого дизайна почти нет. Есть платные библиотеки вроде DevExpress, но там тоже не все так гладко как хотелось бы, в их основе все те же формы, плюс россыпь собственных косяков и тараканов.

Comment: Как фиксируется в wpf размер шрифта элемента? Можете привести пример кода?

Comment: @olga Размер задается в dpi-независимых единицах.

Comment: код от winform будет работать?

Comment: @olga В общем случае нет. Что-то будет, но не многое. Бизнес логика естественно будет работать. Не будет работать все что касается контролов и большинства событий

Comment: @olga Просто там другие свойства, события и логика у контролов

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить некий множитель ко всем размерам шрифта всех контролов на форме? т.е. если вычислить разницу dpi (например, между 96 и 120) и найти значение множителя, то как применить этот множитель ко всем "Font" для всех контролов на форме (изначально размеры шрифтов у контролов разные)?

Comment: @olga к сожалению, никак. Тип Font это структура, т.е. у каждого контроль своя копия шрифта. Только перебирать контролы и менять у каждого :(